# webkit multiple inline shadows

Tags: safari, webkit, css

I have trouble setting multiple shadows on one element in webkit:

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #999, 0 0 5px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #999, 0 0 5px #fff;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #999, 0 0 5px #fff;
```

it works fine in firefox but safari displays only the inset shadow. i tried to set both values separately. But safari takes just count of the last value:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px #fff;
```

is it possible to set more then one shadow on a single element in safari/webkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds stupid, but I think the best documentation for WebKit-specific CSS 3 features is on... MDC, in your case the relevant page is [-moz-box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-box-shadow). It contains an example of a box with multiple shadows, a link to a page containing [more examples](http://www.elektronotdienst-nuernberg.de/bugs/box-shadow_inset.html), as well as a [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-box-shadow#section_6).

As you can see, multiple shadows are only supported from Safari 4.0 (onwards).